# ember simple auth save user profile in a session

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I can't find out why the method `set` of session `this.get('session').set('name', name);` does not persist after having  reloaded the page. I followed exactly what was mentioned [here](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/).

My code

```
//controllers/authentification.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
actions: {
    authenticate() {
        var this2 = this;
        let {
            email, motDePasse
        } = this.getProperties('email', 'motDePasse');

        this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:oauth2', email, motDePasse).then(function () {
            this2.store.queryRecord('membre', {
                membre: {
                    email: email
                }
            }).then(function (membre) {
                var nom = membre.get('nom');
                this2.get('session').set('nom', nom);
                console.log('name:', nom);
            });
        }).catch((reason) => {
            this.set('errorMessage', reason.error || reason);
        });
    }
}
});
```

for the session-store/sessions.js

```
import Cookie from 'ember-simple-auth/session-stores/cookie';

export default Cookie.extend();
```

controllers/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import SessionService from 'ember-simple-auth/services/session';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
    index: function () {
        this.transitionTo('index');
    }
});
```

template/application.js

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
{{#if session.isAuthenticated}}
   <li>nom :{{session.nom}}</li>
   <li><a {{action 'logout' on="click"}}>Deconnecter</a></li>
{{else}}
   {{#link-to 'authentification' tagName="li"}}<a href>Authentification</a>{{/link-to}}
{{/if}}
</ul>
```

the first time i authenticate, the variable "nom" appears but once i reload the page, the variable "nom" disappears but the session stille isAuthenticated

Answer (score 1):

i have found the solution , i have just to use

`this2.get('session').set('.data.nom', nom);`

instead of

```
this2.get('session').set('nom', nom);
```